# fetch XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject using xmpp,but NSManagingContextDidSaveChangesNotification seems not work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xmpp

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedGroupResultsController
{
    if (fetchedGroupResultsController == nil)
    {
        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[self appDelegate] managedObjectContext_roster];


    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:moc];

    NSSortDescriptor *sd1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    //NSSortDescriptor *sd2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"displayName" ascending:YES];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sd1, nil];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];

    fetchedGroupResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                   managedObjectContext:moc
                                                                     sectionNameKeyPath:@"name"
                                                                              cacheName:nil];
    [fetchedGroupResultsController setDelegate:self];

    [sd1 release];
    //[sd2 release];
    [fetchRequest release];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![fetchedGroupResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error performing fetch: %@", error);
    }

}

return fetchedGroupResultsController;
```

}`

I use this method to fetch group result and it works.but when one of my contact online or offline,the 
`- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}`
method won't be called,so my table view won't be reloaded and the state is not refreshed. I am stumped,anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is still useful..

That is because what you fetch is the XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject, not the XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject. Whenever someone is online or offline, XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject in the roster change, so the

`-(void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller { [[self tableView] reloadData];`

will be called.

try to use XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject instead of XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject, and you will see the difference.